# Please I keep getting this error when I try to run my flutter app on android studio

Tags: android

Launching lib\main.dart on Infinix X626 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\LAPTOP\StudioProjects\untitled\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk:
Exception occurred while executing:
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:413)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2415)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:907)
at com.
Error launching application on Infinix X626.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have enough space in your phone/emulator as mentioned in the error

> Requested internal only, but not enough space